# Is it possible to draw an Activity Diagram without the final node?

Tags: uml

If I have two frames in my GUI. (Assume 1st frame ="A" and 2nd frame="B").

when clicked on "A", it redirects to "B".
when Clicked on "B", it redirects to "A".

So it is continuously looping.
Is it possible to draw the Activity Diagram without adding the final node?

note: But anyone can click on the cross mark on top right corner and exit from the program. (Is that means I have to add final node to everywhere??)

Answer (score 2):

You would model it with an interrupt flow like this:

[image]

The dashed boundary represents an interruptible region from where a flash-formed flow can exit at any time.

The `Exit` has not outgoing edges and thus ends the control flow. You might optionally add an outgoing flow to a flow final, though.

Alternatively, if there are many exceptions you could use this variant:

[image]

I doubt that is is really UML compliant, but as I say: "if it serves communication, it's fine". And from the context this looks rather evident.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. ! But, you have added lighting arrows to both of "A" and "B". What if there are lots of tasks like "A" and "B"? Do we need to add lighting arrows to each of them? or is it possible to add just one lighting arrow which starts from the dashed edge?

Comment: This actually mean you have a lot of exceptions. So you should also show them. That might as well be a trigger to re-design the flow. However, the added alternative might be a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An Activity ends when an Action ends and no other Action has the tokens it needs to start. You can find many fUML test cases that work like this, without explicit start and end nodes.